# Using unityplayer in multi activities

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am using unityplayer in sub view of Android following this guide: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/using-unity-android-in-a-sub-view.98315/

It works well in one activity (say ActivityA), then I start ActivityB from ActivtyA. For ActivityB, I am using similar code to add unityplayer into a sub view. But it gets stuck in ActivityB.

But if I remove the unityplayer in ActivityA, making it a normal activity, and then starting ActivityB, then ActivityB is working, the 3D object is showing up in ActivityB.

I am wondering whether there is some way to use unityplayer in multi activities?

Comment: i think this is a valid question to understand life cycle of android as well as unity.